# Using a for loop, how do I iterate an object to add id attributes to them?

Tags: javascript

In the generate function, I need to loop the Box constructor through the boxes array and add a unique id for each new box created.

I'll need to use the counter variable to increase the number of boxes by 1.  The id for each box needs to be a number starting at 1.

It only needs to be basic JavaScript.

```js
function Box(id, name, color, x, y) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.color = color;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

var boxes = [];


var counter = 0;

function generate() {
  for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i] = new Box();
    newBox[i].setAttribute("id", "boxes");
    counter++;
  };
}
```

Comment: Where do you take that newBox variable from, you need to initialize that variable first, add it to the array, then set the attribute. Also your Box Object does not have a function setAttribute.

Comment: I've added the newBox variable but I don't think I'm adding it to the array correctly. - http://jsfiddle.net/mpstring/85k3yr6f/1/

Answer (score 1):

You must actually create an instance using `new` for each `Box` that's going to be in the array.

I suggest that you also pass the desired length into the `generate` function:

```
function generateBoxes(n) {
    var boxes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        boxes[i] = new Box(i, ...);  // supply additional parameters
        // etc
    }
    return boxes;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks.  The amount  to be passed through the loop isactually coming from an html radio button.  I'm still trying to figure out how to get that to work.  Here's what I have if you want to take a look - http://jsfiddle.net/mpstring/85k3yr6f/